# Liquibase check constraint between two tables

Tags: liquibase, check-constraints, changeset, changelog

I want to create two new  columns each one of them is in a different table.
For example: on **compan**y table i want to create a column with name **last_registration_number** and the second column called **registration_number** on **employee** table with **check constraint** that follows this logic

```
 registration_number of employee table <= last_registration_number of company table
```

I couldn't found how to do this between two tables.
What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Liquibase PRO version could help. It has `addCheckConstraint` tag (as well as edit and drop). Here's a link to the [description](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/pro/add-check-constraint.html).

Also there's a `checkConstraint` attribute in `constraints` tag:

```
<createTable tableName="foo">
    <column name="bar" type"integer">
        <constraints checkConstraint="your condition here"/>
    </column>
</createTable>
```

but I'm not sure if it'll work, since the pull request [basics of implementing checkConstraint](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/374/files) is still open.

Or if you can just play around with `sql` tag which allows you to do anything you want in plain SQL.